# Where start code in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i dont know where can i put the code to start a fragment. I have a viewpager with fragments but they dont do nothing. For example:

I have the class fragmentosactivity thats inicialize de fragments:

```
    public class FragmentosActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.fragmentos_layout);

        // Paginador
        this.inicializaPaginas();
        //ActionBar
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Contoles");
        //CirculoProgreso
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.FALSE);       

    }

    //Este metodo inicia todos los fragments
    private void inicializaPaginas() {      

         FragmentAdapter adapter = 
                    new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.addFragment(new Mapa());
            adapter.addFragment(new Cercanos());

            ViewPagerAdapter vadapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( this );

            ViewPager pager =
                (ViewPager)findViewById( R.id.viewpager );
            TitlePageIndicator indicator =
                (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById( R.id.indicator );
            pager.setAdapter( adapter );
            pager.setAdapter( vadapter );
            indicator.setViewPager( pager );

    }

}
```

Here i call cercanos.class
And in cercanos i have

```
public class Cercanos extends ListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cercanos, container, false);

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     String[] objetos = {"hola","adios"};
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objetos));

        Parseador.anadedatos(); 
        }
```

}

But never enter in onCreate method of cercanos, why? I think i dont understand for all the use of fragments.

Answer (score 1):

this is called only in main activity, not in views

```
public class XXX extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
}
}
```

**onCreate** is a fragment of the application life-cycle, not class or view life-cycle

Answer (score 0):

You can try to overriding this method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

And put the onCreate code here.

Anyway, you can take a look at the documentation, because fragments don't have a setContentView, is in the xml layout where you tell what fragment controlls the layout. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Hope this helps